# Multiple counts in a single query with case statements SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to calculate the sum of the number of individuals in a table that meet certain conditions using the case statement. I then need to calculate that number as a percentage of all individuals that belong to that group.

I think that one way of doing this is similar to something as follows

```
with test as (
select sum(case when (datediff(hh, timestamp1, timestamp2) > 2) & testing.X = 10 then 1 else 0 end) AS [Numerator1],
sum(case when (datediff(hh,timestamp1, timestamp2) > 5) & testing.X = 20 then 1 else 0 end) AS [Numerator2], 
sum(case when testing.X = 10 then 1 else 0 end) AS [Denominator1],
sum(case when testing.X = 20 then 1 else 0 end) AS [Denominator2],
testing.id 
from testing
) 
select [Numerator1]/[Denominator1] * 100 as [Target1]
[Numerator2]/[Denominator2] * 100 as [Target2]
from testing 
inner join testing.id = test.id
left join location.location_id = testing.location_id
group by testing.X, testing.location_id
```

How would I do this so that I ultimately end up with a matrix which gives me the two different percentages above? Ideally, I would have only one [Target] variable rather than two so that I can just use the group by statement to split it up.

How would I add a total column which gives me the percentage across two locations? (i.e. for condition testing.X = 10 sum the total number of cases that belong to that category for both locations and calculate the percentage of those cases that met the case statement conditions above)

```
Priority LocationA LocationB TotalRow
A          %          %          % 
B          %          %          % 
TotalCol   %          %
```

Comment: This doesn't look like MySQL

Comment: I get this question a lot. I am not really sure what it means when I am asked for the specific database that I am using. I use Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio.

Comment: There exist many different RDBMS (relational database management systems). One is SQL Server. MySQL is another. And then there are PostgreSQL, Oracle, DB2, MS Access ... It is important with SQL questions that we know the DBMS, because the correct answer may depend on that. I've corrected the tag for you.

Comment: Wonderful - thanks. I take it Management Studio can accomodate more than one RDBMS?

Comment: I think that Microsoft built SSMS for SQL Server only. There are mistakes in your query. First of all you create a `test` view, but don't use it. You use `tes` instead. But then you tell us, that `test` and `testing` are the same table. What do you mean? One is the copy of the other? Then, `left outer join testing.id` and `left outer join location.location_id` are incorrect. You cannot join columns, you join tables. E.g. `left outer join testing on testing.id = tes.id`. But then, why would you do this, if `tes` and `testing are identical`? And why outer join, when you know there is a match?

Comment: And why do you join with `location` at all? And what is `tes.X`? Why are using bit operations (`&`)? Is this supposed to be `AND`? Then you are talking about individuals, but I don't see any reference to some "individual"  in the query. Please correct all your errors. Enhance your explanation. Tell us about your tables, i.e. what they contain, what the columns represent, what the primary keys are.

Comment: I have added a table to the original post which demonstrates the end goal. In essence, I need a percentage that is grouped by priority and location. The TotalRow column in the cross-tab adds the numerators across both locations and is divided by the new denominator (whatever that may be). TotalCol would be the percentage of all cases with either priority that met the condition.

I took a stab at the code - it could be entirely misled, but the matrix/cross-tab is what I am after.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are almost there but was wondering if you could consider creating an extra column which classifies your criteria e.g.

### COLUMN Z

Group 1
Group 2

You could then include this column in your Group By?